# Swift/UIView Draw something like tachometer

Tags: swift, uiview, draw

I think I am having kind of a blackout but I am not able to simply work with BezierPaths within Swift. Want I want to do is something like on the screenshot:
[image]

So it's just something like a tachometer with three colours:

What I do have is the following:

```
diagram.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
    diagram.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    let pi = CGFloat(Float.pi)
    let start:CGFloat = 0.0
    let end :CGFloat = pi
    let radius : CGFloat = diagram.frame.width/3
    let middle = CGPoint(x: diagram.frame.size.width/2, y:diagram.frame.size.height/2)

    let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath();
    path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(x: middle.x, y: middle.y),
        radius: radius,
        startAngle: start,
        endAngle: end,
        clockwise: false
    )

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.path = path.cgPath
    diagram.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

That is just the first arc, but it makes me crazy. It is not centred, which is odd because I am using the size of my Uiview for it. My UIView is obviously called "diagram".

Does anyone have a great example with Swift how to do something like on the screenshot?
Thanks for reading!

=======
This is just code relating to the answer of andykkt

```
func drawCompareGauge(frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 180, height: 92), leftPercentage: CGFloat = 0.5) {
    //// General Declarations
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //// Color Declarations
    let leftColor = UIColor(red: 0.278, green: 0.757, blue: 0.749, alpha: 1.000)
    let rightColor = UIColor(red: 0.557, green: 0.400, blue: 0.867, alpha: 1.000)

    //// Variable Declarations
    let leftDashed: CGFloat = 247 * leftPercentage

    //// rightRing Drawing
    let rightRingPath = UIBezierPath()
    rightRingPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 11.5, y: frame.minY + 91.5))
    rightRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 42.73, y: frame.minY + 28.82), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 11.5, y: frame.minY + 65.89), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 23.76, y: frame.minY + 43.15))
    rightRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 90, y: frame.minY + 13), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 55.88, y: frame.minY + 18.89), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 72.25, y: frame.minY + 13))
    rightRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 168.5, y: frame.minY + 91.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 133.35, y: frame.minY + 13), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 168.5, y: frame.minY + 48.15))
    rightColor.setStroke()
    rightRingPath.lineWidth = 23
    context?.saveGState()
    //CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, [247, 247], 2)
    //context!.setLineDash(phase: <#T##CGFloat#>, lengths: <#T##[CGFloat]#>)
    context?.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [247,247])
    //problem
    rightRingPath.stroke()
    context?.restoreGState()


    //// leftRing Drawing
    let leftRingPath = UIBezierPath()
    leftRingPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 11.5, y: frame.minY + 91.5))
    leftRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 42.73, y: frame.minY + 28.82), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 11.5, y: frame.minY + 65.89), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 23.76, y: frame.minY + 43.15))
    leftRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 90, y: frame.minY + 13), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 55.88, y: frame.minY + 18.89), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 72.25, y: frame.minY + 13))
    leftRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 168.5, y: frame.minY + 91.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 133.35, y: frame.minY + 13), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 168.5, y: frame.minY + 48.15))
    leftColor.setStroke()
    leftRingPath.lineWidth = 23
    context?.saveGState()
    //context!.setLineDash(context, 0, [leftDashed, 247], 2)
    //Problem
    context?.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [leftDashed,247])
    leftRingPath.stroke()
    context?.restoreGState()


    //// Text Drawing
    let textRect = CGRect(x: frame.minX + 7, y: frame.minY + 74, width: 11, height: 21)
    let textTextContent = NSString(string: "L")
    let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    textStyle.alignment = .left

    let textFontAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: textStyle]

    let textTextHeight: CGFloat = textTextContent.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: textRect.width, height: CGFloat.infinity), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: textFontAttributes, context: nil).size.height
    context?.saveGState()
    context?.clip(to: textRect)
    textTextContent.draw(in: CGRect(x: textRect.minX, y: textRect.minY + (textRect.height - textTextHeight) / 2, width: textRect.width, height: textTextHeight), withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
    context?.restoreGState()


    //// Text 2 Drawing
    let text2Rect = CGRect(x: frame.minX + 164, y: frame.minY + 76, width: 11, height: 17)
    let text2TextContent = NSString(string: "R")
    let text2Style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    text2Style.alignment = .left

    let text2FontAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: text2Style]

    let text2TextHeight: CGFloat = text2TextContent.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: text2Rect.width, height: CGFloat.infinity), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: text2FontAttributes, context: nil).size.height
    context?.saveGState()
    context?.clip(to: text2Rect)
    //CGContextClipToRect(context!, text2Rect)
    text2TextContent.draw(in: CGRect(x: text2Rect.minX, y: text2Rect.minY + (text2Rect.height - text2TextHeight) / 2, width: text2Rect.width, height: text2TextHeight), withAttributes: text2FontAttributes)
    context?.restoreGState()
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but why not simply `withCenter: middle` and `CGFloat.pi`

Comment: You are right, I could have done that. Thanks :)

Comment: Btw you can use the view center property `diagram.center`. `path.addArc(withCenter: diagram.center, radius: diagram.frame.width / 4, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: false)
`

Comment: You should be using the `bounds`, not the `frame`.  The drawing of the view shouldn't change based upon where the view is placed in its superview.

Comment: One of the option is to use tools like "PaintCode", you can draw and export code.

Answer (score 1):

I draw it from "PaintCode" as an example, you can use paintcode to draw how you want it to be.

```
@IBDesignable class GaugeView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var leftPercentage: CGFloat = 0.708 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var otherPercentage: CGFloat = 0.206 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    drawCompareGauge(frame: bounds, leftPercentage: leftPercentage, otherPercentage: otherPercentage)
}

func drawCompareGauge(frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 180, height: 92), leftPercentage: CGFloat = 0.708, otherPercentage: CGFloat = 0.206) {
    //// General Declarations
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    //// Color Declarations
    let leftColor = UIColor(red: 0.278, green: 0.757, blue: 0.749, alpha: 1.000)
    let rightColor = UIColor(red: 0.557, green: 0.400, blue: 0.867, alpha: 1.000)
    let otherColor = UIColor(red: 0.800, green: 0.320, blue: 0.320, alpha: 1.000)

    //// Variable Declarations
    let leftDashed: CGFloat = 247 * leftPercentage
    let otherDashed: CGFloat = 247 * otherPercentage

    //// rightRing Drawing
    let rightRingPath = UIBezierPath()
    rightRingPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 11.5, y: frame.minY + 91.5))
    rightRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 42.73, y: frame.minY + 28.82), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 11.5, y: frame.minY + 65.89), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 23.76, y: frame.minY + 43.15))
    rightRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 90, y: frame.minY + 13), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 55.88, y: frame.minY + 18.89), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 72.25, y: frame.minY + 13))
    rightRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 168.5, y: frame.minY + 91.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 133.35, y: frame.minY + 13), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 168.5, y: frame.minY + 48.15))
    rightColor.setStroke()
    rightRingPath.lineWidth = 23
    context.saveGState()
    context.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [247, 247])
    rightRingPath.stroke()
    context.restoreGState()


    //// leftRing Drawing
    let leftRingPath = UIBezierPath()
    leftRingPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 11.5, y: frame.minY + 91.5))
    leftRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 42.73, y: frame.minY + 28.82), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 11.5, y: frame.minY + 65.89), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 23.76, y: frame.minY + 43.15))
    leftRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 90, y: frame.minY + 13), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 55.88, y: frame.minY + 18.89), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 72.25, y: frame.minY + 13))
    leftRingPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 168.5, y: frame.minY + 91.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 133.35, y: frame.minY + 13), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 168.5, y: frame.minY + 48.15))
    leftColor.setStroke()
    leftRingPath.lineWidth = 23
    context.saveGState()
    context.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [leftDashed, 247])
    leftRingPath.stroke()
    context.restoreGState()


    //// leftRing 2 Drawing
    let leftRing2Path = UIBezierPath()
    leftRing2Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 11.5, y: frame.minY + 91.5))
    leftRing2Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 42.73, y: frame.minY + 28.82), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 11.5, y: frame.minY + 65.89), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 23.76, y: frame.minY + 43.15))
    leftRing2Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 90, y: frame.minY + 13), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 55.88, y: frame.minY + 18.89), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 72.25, y: frame.minY + 13))
    leftRing2Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 168.5, y: frame.minY + 91.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 133.35, y: frame.minY + 13), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 168.5, y: frame.minY + 48.15))
    otherColor.setStroke()
    leftRing2Path.lineWidth = 23
    context.saveGState()
    context.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [otherDashed, 247])
    leftRing2Path.stroke()
    context.restoreGState()
}
```

I have changed the code to class and support latest xcode & swift. You can just place a this view on view controller to see the result and change `leftPercentage` animate gauge.

==============================

I have updated the code to display 3 different value as gauge, I hope this help you to figure it out.  Please see below gif for this control in action.

[image: Gauge in action]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I took a while to have a look on your code. Unfortunately, I am using Swift 4 so there have been hundreds of changes /refactors, but now I am sure I refactored everything. I posted my new code into the topic.
Unfortunately, it's just blank. Am I using something wrong?

Comment: I just would like to see the result, before I can start to understand the code itself.

Comment: I am using the function itself like you did in the example with drawCompareGauge(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 180, height: 92), leftPercentage: 0.5)

Comment: @FranzFerdinand Sorry paintcode version I have doesn't support latest swift code. I have fixed the issue.

Comment: Hey, I now had time to check the code. I did understand the part about the text (L and R) but I need help to understand the drawing part. You did used exactly the same points for the left and the right curve but in the end, it's making what I wanted to do. How does that work? And what is setLineDash for. I am trying to understand it and than make it responsive, centred and with three colours.

Comment: @FranzFerdinand I have update the code, please check.